# Multiple Scores In One Application

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Hy,

I have a game with multiple levels and I would like to post the user high score separately for each level.

1.1 Is This possible? Does Facebook support posting multiple scores for the same application?

If this is not possible I had an idea to post a long number which starts with the digit 1, after that the next 3 digits represent the score for the first level, the next 3 digits for the second level and so on. I have 7 levels that adds up to a 22 digit number.

2.1 Is it possible to post a 22 digit number as a score?

2.2 Is this score diplayed anywhere on the users timeline / on the page
    of the application or it is hidden from the users and I can do my
    workaround safely?

Thanks in advance,
Bari

UPDATE:

2.1 In the documentation the score appears as an Integer so posting a 22 digit number is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, there is no way to publish multiple scores in one application :(

It's not a good idea to post scores which are concatenation of multiple scores because whenever you post scores then facebook automatically pusblish the number that you sent to the "Games feed" so everyone will see this strange number. Moreover, when one user passes his friend score then it's also published to the "Games feed" so it's problematic to send a score that doesn't represent a real score